# Kivy how to have one class and method for multiple dropdowns?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy

I am making an app where I will have many different labels for dropdown lists. These dropdown lists will be activated by a button that will show the dropdown.
My problem is that I do not know how to have multiple dropdowns using only one class in my python code. Currently, I have to make multiple classes and multiple methods to activate different dropdown menus and to have those dropdown menus come from different classes.

Trying to modify the `show_dropDown()` didn't work since i couldn't get the labels to show and the button to link the dropdown menu from.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

Window.size = (286.110236, 570.33070866)


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class CustomDropDown(DropDown):
    pass


class CustomDropDown2(DropDown):
    pass


class ButtonGrid(ButtonBehavior, GridLayout):
    def show_dropDown(self):
        dropdown = CustomDropDown()
        dropdown.open(self)

    def show_dropDown2(self):
        dropdown = CustomDropDown2()
        dropdown.open(self)


GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI


MainApp().run()
```

kv-file:

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<ButtonGrid>:
<CustomDropdown>:
    id: dropdown
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: 'Dropdown 1'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 400
        background_color: (0, 1, 0, .9)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

<CustomDropdown2>:
    id: dropdown2
    Label:
        id: label2
        text: 'Dropdown 2'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 400
        background_color: (1, 0, 1, .9)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos


<HomeScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#FFFFFF")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos:  self.pos
        GridLayout:
            rows: 8
            cols: 1
            spacing: 10
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 1200
            width: self.minimum_width

            ButtonGrid:
                id: button1
                cols:1
                rows:1
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 185.71
                on_press:
                    self.show_dropDown()
                background_color: (1,0,0,1)
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: self.background_color
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                Label:
                    text: "Button 1"

            ButtonGrid:
                id: button2
                cols:1
                rows:1
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 185.71
                on_press:
                    self.show_dropDown2()
                background_color: (0,0,1,1)
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: self.background_color
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                Label:
                    text: "Button 2"
```

Comment: Try to be more specific. Especially what makes your `DropDown`s different from one another? If it is just the `text` of the corresponding `Label` then just add that property.

Comment: Sorry! What makes each `DropDown` different is the `ButtonGrid` they are attached to (I want each dropdown to be "linked" to a specific `ButtonGrid`). As well, the Label of the text will be different for each DropDown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add property (or properties) to your `CustomDropDown` class (or may be to `ButtonGrid`) and link it to associated widget as follows:

First in `.py`

```py
class CustomDropDown(DropDown):
    text = StringProperty("")
```

Then in `.kv`

```py
<CustomDropdown>:
    id: dropdown
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: root.text
        size_hint_y: None
        ...
```

Now call them as you need with some added args/kwargs,

```py
        ...
        GridLayout:
            rows: 8
            cols: 1
            spacing: 10
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 1200
            width: self.minimum_width

            ButtonGrid:
                id: button1
                cols:1
                rows:1
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 185.71
                on_press:
                    self.show_dropDown('Dropdown 1')
                background_color: (1,0,0,1)
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: self.background_color
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                Label:
                    text: "Button 1"

            ButtonGrid:
                id: button2
                cols:1
                rows:1
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 185.71
                on_press:
                    self.show_dropDown(value='Dropdown 2')
                background_color: (0,0,1,1)
```

And handle those calls in one go,

```py
class ButtonGrid(ButtonBehavior, GridLayout):
    def show_dropDown(self, value = ""):
        dropdown = CustomDropDown(text = value)
        dropdown.open(self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise and well written answer! I could then use this same concept to change other values of `dropdown` such as the background colour, correct?

Comment: Yes ! That's exactly what I indicated in *'You can add property (or properties)...'*.